# Systemd watchdog running program via a script

Tags: python, bash, ros, systemd, watchdog

I have this python code which I need to run using `systemd` and monitor if it is hung as well. The problem is, when I run the python script directly from systemd, it works fine. However when the python script is run from another shell script which is run from my systemd service, it says

```
sdping_py.service: Got notification message from PID 6828, but reception only permitted for main PID 6768
```

The problem seems to be the python script running as a child process of the shell script and systemd service expecting notifications from the shell script which is the main process for the service. How can I get around this? My application strictly needs to be run from a shell script.

Here's the python code I tried,

```
import sdnotify, time

n = sdnotify.SystemdNotifier()
print("Gonna start")
time.sleep(2)
print("Started!")

n.notify("READY=1")
i=0
while True:
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
    n.notify("WATCHDOG=1")
    i+=1
```

This is my service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Test watchdog Demo process
DefaultDependencies=false
Requires=basic.target

[Service]
Type=notify
WatchdogSec=2
ExecStart=/home/teshanl/sdping/scripts/sdping_py.sh
#ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/teshanl/sdping/src/sdping_pub.py
StartLimitInterval=5min
StartLimitBurst=5
#StartLimitAction=reboot
Restart=always
```

And this is the shell file

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/python /home/teshanl/sdping/src/sdping_pub.py
```

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @georgexsh, adding `exec` to the shell command solved my problem partially. My new question is how do I do the same with a `roslaunch` command? A ROS node should be sending the heartbeat notification to the `systemd` service. `roslaunch` launches the nodes with seperate PIDs obviously

Comment: if your shell script is that simple, you could use `exec`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. Could you please explain? And this is a sample program that I showed here. The actual shell script might contain several lines of code

Comment: like `exec /usr/bin/python ...`

Comment: That worked! Thanks. That will be a partial solution to my problem

Comment: Regarding `roslaunch`: `roslaunch` has a [Python API](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage) which might help you. With it, it is possible to launch and monitor nodes from a Python script. The documentation is not very complete, though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `exec`, to replace the bash process with python process:

```
exec /usr/bin/python ...
```

or set [`NotifyAccess`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#NotifyAccess=) to `all`, to allow the forked child python process sent sd message, see [this thread](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2018-January/040207.html).